# How to load an internet inputstream faster?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpresponse

I'm developing an Android app which communicates with a web service. The webservice gets me some geometry files and because of that those files can get really really large.

Because you can't wait 1-3 minutes until you got the response I need to lower the loading time.

So here is some Code:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[1000000];

    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
      buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Log.d("ARks", (endTime - startTime) / 1000 + " seconds");
```

The time it takes to do this is always between 50 and 75 seconds (and this with rather small files).

Is there a way to speed this thing up? Maybe some Android specific stuff to allow the app more bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

If you *know* that bandwidth is your problem, compress your stream: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html

And if you don't need all the data before you can process it, reduce the size of your buffer. This will allow you to process some objects while others are coming across the wire.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to compress the stream on the server and directly send the compressed stream to my client?

Comment: @PeterKnukeOberrauner - yes, but as a new user I can only put one link in the answer.

Comment: What link did you want to put in your answer? 

Oh. I don't have enough access to edit the server code. :/

Comment: @PeterKnukeOberrauner - I would have added links for both `GZIPInputStream` (for the client) and `GZIPOutputStream` (for the server). However, once you get to one, the other is easy to find :-)